# Using Jquery to cycle through input fields when MaxLength is reached

Tags: jquery, html

I have found several suggested solutions for this but none seems to work with my situation due to all my inputs being nested inside div tags. Below is a sample row. I have several of these rows on a data entry form. I'm looking to advance to the next input field when the maxlength of 7 is entered into any input. The user will enter xxx.xxx where x is any number in any or all of the inputs fields. I'm trying to make it so they don't have to leave the numeric keypad. Any help would be appreciated.

this is my attempt [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbconrad/mprhjby3/)

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <span><label class="control-label">2.5</label></span>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CouponTypeID must be a number." data-val-required="The CouponTypeID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponTypeID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponTypeID" type="hidden" value="4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="67">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="68">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="69">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you place your code in js fiddle?

Comment: updated the OP with a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hidden inputs in the form that are being selected when using `$('input')`. You need to select all the non hidden inputs `$('input').not(':hidden')` and if your form has input types other than text (radio, checkbox...etc) then your selection shall be `$('input[type="text"]')` (this also works for the current case).

Besides, when the index of the element + 1 reaches the length of the inputs then set the next element index as 0 to keep the cycle :

```
((inputs.index($(this)) + 1) == inputs.length) ? 0 : inputs.index($(this)) + 1;
```

Snippet:

```js
var inputs = $('input').not(':hidden').on('keydown', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13){
        //Enter
      
        var next  = ((inputs.index($(this)) + 1) == inputs.length) ? 0 : inputs.index($(this)) + 1;
        inputs.eq(next).focus();
    }
    
    //event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <span><label class="control-label">2.5</label></span>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CouponTypeID must be a number." data-val-required="The CouponTypeID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponTypeID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponTypeID" type="hidden" value="4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_0__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[0].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="67">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_1__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[1].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="68">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 border-div col-main">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OpenAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__OpenAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].OpenAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Close Amount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__CloseAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].CloseAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HighAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__HighAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].HighAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-values">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LowAmount must be a number." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__LowAmount" maxlength="7" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].LowAmount" type="text" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SettlementMonthID must be a number." data-val-required="The SettlementMonthID field is required." id="DailyTradeData_Coupons_0__CouponValues_2__SettlementMonthID" name="DailyTradeData.Coupons[0].CouponValues[2].SettlementMonthID" type="hidden" value="69">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to accept any input at all. Neither numeric or alpha

Comment: Thats because of `event.preventDefault();`. check the edit

Comment: I thought I took that out when I put it in the fiddle.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle but it's still not working as I would expect https://jsfiddle.net/tbconrad/mprhjby3/12/

Comment: You have some errors, there is nothing defined as `$this`, it shall be `$(this)`, besides you need to include jquery library `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: yes, that was it. I had copied that from what I assumed was a working snippet and didn't check it. Thanks. Now it's working as I would expect.

Comment: One additional item. I can't delete anything from the input. Thoughts?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Get total length of input textbox and check if it's last textbox with use of index then get the focus to first textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 var inputs = $('input').on('keydown', function(event){
  var total = inputs.length;
  var inds = inputs.index(this);;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13){
        //Enter
  if(inds < total-1){
        inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }
  else if(inds == total-1){
   inputs.eq(total - inputs.index(this) -1).focus();
  }
    } 
    
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 0px">1</div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="4" name="a[]">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="b[]">
    </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="c[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 0px">2</div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="4" name="a[]">
    </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="b[]">
    </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="c[]">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to accept any input at all. Neither numeric or alpha