# Unable to delete data in an input field

Tags: jquery

So this question is based on my initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787767/using-jquery-to-cycle-through-input-fields-when-maxlength-is-reached/35788978) which was answered and working. However, I find that now I am unable to delete the data from the input if the need arises. I added the keycode monitor which should allow the backspace or the delete key to bypass the jump but it doesn't seem to be working.

here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbconrad/mprhjby3/)

```
var inputs = $('input').not(':hidden').on('keydown', function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode !== 8 || keycode !== 46) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"), 10)) {
      var next = ((inputs.index($(this)) + 1) == inputs.length) ? 0 : inputs.index($(this)) + 1;
      inputs.eq(next).focus();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6nsbzvkt/?

Comment: @Vohuman thanks I thinks this one actually functions better than mine.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
...
if (keycode !== 8 && keycode !== 46) {
...
```

otherwise this condition always success

Comment: @Tim because if `keycode===8` then `keycode !== 46` return true. In other words `OR` operator means if one of the conditions success

Comment: duh, YeahI was thinking something else. Makes perfect sense thanks,